# How can I import .dat files in scripts?

Tags: scripting, import

I want to import .dat files. I can import .dat files clicking option in menu, cause  I've install an plugin from [here](https://github.com/TobyLobster/ImportLDraw). But I don't know how to import .dat files in scripts.

I have tried read the plugin's code. The plugin's code has a folder structure like this:

```
-images/
-loadldraw/
 -loadldraw.py
-importldraw.py
```

In importldraw.py, I found something might be relevant to my question: 
  loadldraw.loadFromFile(self, self.filepath)
I put my script named render_script.py and files above in the same folder. But after I import loadldraw and code relevant above in my script, an error occurred. My script and the error are shown below:

```
#render_scripts.py
import bpy
from bpy import context
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\HL\Desktop\blender_script\importldraw')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\HL\Desktop\blender_script\loadldraw')
import importldraw
import loadldraw
path = 'D:/lego_part/ldraw/parts/8.dat'

my = loadldraw.loadFromFile(importldraw.ImportLDrawOps, r'D:\lego_part\ldraw\parts\8.dat')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\render_script.py", line 7, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\HL\Desktop\blender_script\importldraw.py", line 111, in <module>
    class ImportLDrawOps(bpy.types.Operator, ImportHelper):
  File "C:\Users\HL\Desktop\blender_script\importldraw.py", line 134, in ImportLDrawOps
    default=prefs.get("ldrawDirectory", loadldraw.Configure.findDefaultLDrawDirectory())
AttributeError: module 'loadldraw' has no attribute 'Configure'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

I neither know how to fix the error nor know how to import .dat files in script. Can someone help me? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)